# Put reaction to bot message

Tags: discord

```
// Embeds
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if(message.content == "sendtest") {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    // Top
    .setAuthor("Informacja systemowa", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/933289723252850729/940680716574933022/Wymiar_Logo_kopia.png")
    .setTitle("Informacja")
    .setDescription("Test")
    // Settings
    .setColor("BLURPLE")
    // Field
    .addField("***Strona naszego serwera:***", "www.ViceMTA.pl", true)
    .addField("***Adress IP:***", "188.165.19.26:22018", true)
    // Zawartosc
    .setImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/933289723252850729/940681715335184495/Banner.gif?size=69")
    // Copyright
    .setFooter(" \nVice MTA 2.0 ©️ 2021 - 2023")
    message.channel.send({embeds : [ embed ]})
    //message.channel.send("|| @everyone ||")
  }
})
```

How to make the bot add a reaction to its message?
As I have already tried in many ways and I can not cope with it, I am asking for effective help. I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

just store when you send your embed in variable like that

```js
const msg = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

then to react it use

```js
await msg.react('')
```